# Python: print similar words from multiple files, exclude words from single file, and print the result to a new file?

Tags: python, text-files

I'm taking an introductory course on Python. I'm currently working with Python 3.7.1. I have 6 text files: file_a.txt, file_b.txt, file_c.txt, file_d.txt, file_e.txt, and stop_words.txt

I have to compare files 'a' through 'e' and find the words that appear in all of them. I have to write the resulting words into a new file ('compare_out.txt'). However, none of the words in stop_words.txt are allowed to show up in textcompare.txt.

I was quite overwhelmed, since I'm a total beginner when it comes to code. We're allowed to be as tedious as possible, as long as the problem is solved.

Here's what I got so far. I tried to work with only file_a to see what I could do, but the code only prints the very last word of the text file. I know I should have used \n to make it prettier, but it seems to mess up the code. This also happens if I exclude the 'encoding = 'utf-8'' in every file I open:

```
import os
os.chdir(#path)
with open('file_a.txt', 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as a, open('file_b.txt', 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as b, open('file_c.txt', 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as c, open('file_d.txt', 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as d, open('file_e.txt', 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as e:
lines_a = a.readlines()
for line in lines_a:
    words_a = line.split()
    for word in words_a:
        ufil = open('compare_out.txt', 'w', encoding = 'utf-8')
        ufil.write(word)
        ufil.close()
```

Thanks in advance, and please excuse me if the question has already been answered somewhere. I did my best to search for something as complicated the last couple of days.

Comment: Not able to test it right now, but I'm pretty sure ufil.write is just overwriting the first line every time. In the open(...) command, try replacing 'w' (for write) with 'a' (for append)

Comment: It does your education absolutely no good if we solve the entire problem for you. If you really are stuck, you need to narrow the question to *one, specific* issue, although likely when you do so, you'll find the answer yourself.

Comment: Sorry for not being specific. This particular problem is part of a much bigger assignment, and this is the part I'm struggling with. I'm glad for your concern, but I'm not trying to "cheat" in any way. Not intentionally at least.

Answer (score 0):

```
_all = []
with open('file_a.txt', 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as a:
    a_list = a.read().split(' ')
    _all.append(a_list)
    with open('file_b.txt', 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as b:
        b_list = b.read().split(' ')
        _all.append(b_list)
        with open('file_c.txt', 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as c:
            c_list = c.read().split(' ')
            _all.append(c_list)
            with open('file_d.txt', 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as d:
                d_list = d.read().split(' ')
                _all.append(d_list)
                with open('file_e.txt', 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as e:
                    e_list = e.read().split(' ')
                    _all.append(e_list)

result = set(_all[0])
for s in _all[1:]:
    result.intersection_update(s)
with open('compare_out.txt', 'w', encoding = 'utf-8') as ufill:
for each in result:
    ufill.writelines(each + '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome here ! First of all, I think you need to split your program into separable action. Don't try to do everything at once. You have to consider as well that you don't need to test every word of every file. Let me explain.

For every step of your algorithm, you will have two entities compared. The first time the file A is compared with file B, and the common words will be put on a list. The second time, the two entities will be that list with common words and file C. From that list, every words which is not in file C will be removed. You do that for every file until the end.

I tried to do this, not tested yet but it give you a first insight:

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords 
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize 
import os
os.chdir(#path)

files_names = ["file_a.txt", "file_b.txt", "and so on"]
common_list = None # will hold the list common words

stop_words = # assuming you have list of stop words 

for i in range(1, len(file_names)):
    # Declare variables
    left = None
    right = None

    # If this is the first loop, get the 0 element of the list (file_a.txt)
    if not common_list:
        with(files_names[i-1], 'r' as f:
            left = f.read().replace('\n', '')
    else: # If not, get the common list
        left = common_list

    # Get the right file
    with open(files_names[i], 'r') as f:
        right = f.read().replace('\n', '')

    # convert string into list
    left = word_tokenize(left)
    right = word_tokenize(right)

    # removing stop words from this list
    left = [w for w in left if not w in stop_words] 
    right = [w for w in right if not w in stop_words] 

    # removing words from common_list hold in right variable
    # that is not on the right file
    left = [w for w in left if not w in right]

    # Put left in common_list for next loop
    common_list = left

    # write your result in file
    with open('compare_out.txt', 'w') as out:
        out.write(common_list)
        out.close()
```

So here is the step:

- Get file a and file b, put it in a list and remove stop words using nltk
- Compare this file and put the result in common_list
- Get file c, put it in a list and remove stop words
- Remove word in common list that is not in file c
- Do it again with file d and so on, until the end.

Answer (score 0):

An example below. Suggest study each of the concepts and if it doesn't make sense re-write that part to how you like. Read up on:

- for loops
- data structures, list[] and set()
- string handling, striping white space

  ```
      import os
      #os.chdir(#path) //assume files in same directory as *.py file

      def read_words_from_list_of_files(list_of_file_names):
          """From a list of files returns a set of words contained in the files"""
          # Make a list of words from the file (assume words separated by white space)
          words_list = []
          for file_name in list_of_file_names:
              with open(file_name, 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
                  for line_read in f:
                      line = line_read.strip()
                      words_in_this_line = line.split(" ")
                      words_list += words_in_this_line
          return set(words_list)

      FILES_OF_INCLUDED_WORDS = ['file_a.txt', 'file_b.txt', 'file_c.txt', 'file_d.txt',  'file_e.txt']
      EXCLUDED_WORDS_FILES = ['stop_words.txt']
      OUTPUT_FILE_NAME = 'compare_out.txt'
      set_of_words_to_include = read_words_from_list_of_files(FILES_OF_INCLUDED_WORDS)
      set_of_words_to_exclude = read_words_from_list_of_files(EXCLUDED_WORDS_FILES)
      # Make a set to eliminate duplicates in the list
      set_of_remaining_words = set_of_words_to_include - set_of_words_to_exclude
      with open(OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, 'w') as f:
          for word in set_of_remaining_words:
              f.write(word + " ") #There will be a space after the last word but maybe this is OK
      print(set_of_remaining_words)
  ```